# Implementing a scale screen transition with React Native?

Tags: react-native

Im trying to implement a screen transition effect, when a user clicks on a Box Component (inside a ScrollView), the image will `scale` and move to the top, Airbnb has a great example of this:

[Airbnb scale transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY6cP.gif)

```
    <ScrollView>
       <Box /> // onPress the scaleImage comp should move to top screen
       <Box /> // regardless of scroll position
       <Box /> 
       <Box />
    ...
   </ScrollView>

   <Animated.Image 
         style={styles.scaleImage} 
         source={this.state.activeImage} />
```

I know how to implement the animation part of this, but the problem Im having is the layout, if the images that Im trying to scale and move to the top are in a ScrollView, how can I determine the distance to get to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using React Native's [`measure`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemethodsmixin.html#measure) function. You can give it any native component (`View`, `ListView`, `Image`, etc.) and it will give you that component's offsets to its frame (the native view which contains it), its page (the screen borders), and its width/height in a callback as soon as rendering is done (or immediately, if rendering is already done)

To get a reference to your image component, define it as:

```
<Image ref="myImage" /*...*/ />
```

Then, within your component class, you can do:

```
this.refs.myImage.measure((frameX, frameY ,width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
  //do stuff with the measurements
})
```

In your case, you would likely want to use `pageX` and `pageY` as they will give you the absolute position of your image. Just remember this function only works on native components and not on user-defined components, so you should call it on the actual `Image` component and not on any wrappers you define around it.

Comment: thanks, that did it. measure should be better documented.